# My method cant round 1,66666 (5.0 / 3)

Tags: java, floating-point, rounding

```
public static double round(double number,int numberofdecimals){
    int n=1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= numberofdecimals;i++){
        n=n*10;
    }


    double  c =((number - Math.floor(number))*n);
    c= Math.floor(c);

    return (Math.floor(number) + (c/n));
}
```

My method is rounding some doubles perfectly but when I put ((5.0 / 3) ,2) in my number parameter it is giving me **1.6600000** what is going on?

Comment: This is simply because the floating point math is broken. See this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: I editet the method broj was the number but in my languge i forgot to translate it to english , it is not the problem tho

Comment: It looks like the problem is just due to precision being lost during the calculations. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate) for more information.

Comment: Milos, please have a look at the question posted by @Blue and see if it has enough information to help you resolve your issue.  (hint: it should).

Comment: not sure what other result you could be expecting, given that you explicitely use `floor`

Comment: what result do you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want to do standard rounding (1.5 rounds to 2.0; 1.49 rounds to 1.0) then try the following:

```
public static double round(double number,int numberofdecimals){
    int n=1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= numberofdecimals;i++){
        n=n*10;
    }

    double  c =((number - Math.floor(number))*n); // Here c = 66.6666666...
    c= Math.floor(c + 0.5); // Now c is 67.0.

    return (Math.floor(number) + (c/n)); // returns 1.67
}
```

Comment: For my purposes this solvers the problem , thanks alot dude.